# How to cancel an Async task in gallery View in android using position index?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have an galleyview which loads images from server album. but my album has many images [more than 500]. so once i scroll the galleyview more fast the number of background task is getting high so the app is getting crashed.so i am planning to kill [cancel] some old tasks based on the position in the galleryview. so please suggest some solution.The source code  is provided below.

**Task invoking:**

```
DownloadImageTask downloadTask = new DownloadImageTask(                             

ShowGallery.this, view,position);

// cancel some task to avoid the crash - need to implement

// cancelPotentialDownload(position);

downloadTask.execute( THUMB_PREFIX + picture.getFileName(),
picture.getForceExtension(), thumbUrl,albumName, bitmapsCache, position, picture,null);


private static boolean cancelPotentialDownload(int position) {

// need to implement.       

}
```

**Downloadimage task**

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {
    Context activity;
    private ImageView view;
    public int position;

    public DownloadImageTask(Context context, ImageView imageView, int imagePosition) {
        super();
        activity = context;
        view = imageView;
        position = imagePosition;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... parameters) {
        String fileName = (String) parameters[0];
        String extension = (String) parameters[1];
        String thumbUrl = (String) parameters[2];
        Integer currentAlbumName = (Integer) parameters[3];
        Map<Integer, Bitmap> bitmapsCache = (Map<Integer, Bitmap>) parameters[4];
        Integer position = (Integer) parameters[5];
        Picture picture = (Picture) parameters[6];
        Album album = (Album) parameters[7];

        Bitmap downloadImage = null;
        File imageFileOnExternalDirectory = null;
        try {
            imageFileOnExternalDirectory = FileUtils.getInstance()
                    .getFileFromGallery(activity, fileName, extension,
                            thumbUrl, true, currentAlbumName);
            downloadImage = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imageFileOnExternalDirectory.getPath());
            if (picture != null) {
                // only for showgallery activity
                picture.setThumbImageCachePath(imageFileOnExternalDirectory
                        .getPath());
                bitmapsCache.put(position, downloadImage);
            } else if (album != null) {
                // only for albumadapter
                album.setAlbumCoverCachePath(imageFileOnExternalDirectory
                        .getPath());
            }
        } catch (GalleryConnectionException e) {

            // Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (FileHandlingException e) {

            // Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        return downloadImage;
    }

    @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap downloadImage) {

        if (downloadImage != null) {
            view.setImageBitmap(downloadImage);


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example on this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html). You are not downloading images from the web, so just replace this functionality with reading the image from gallery